# How to Compare Dates and Times?

Tags: java

How can I compare whether two datetimes are the same or at least overlap?

For example, let's say we have the following two sets of start and stop times:

> Start time: 2011-07-21 9:00am  Stop time:  2011-07-21 10:00am
>
> Start time: 2011-07-21 9:05am Stop time: 2011-07-21 10:30am

The datetimes do not match exactly, so I can't do a straight equality test. However, for my purposes the datetimes overlap is sufficient to be deemed a match, how can I test for this type of overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend to use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) and its [overlap](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#overlap%28org.joda.time.ReadableInterval%29) method.

From javadoc, it will not only tell you if it two intervals overlap. But it tells you what the overlapping interval is.

> Returns:
>       the overlap interval, null if no overlap

Answer (score 0):

Use [JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) or write a DateRange class of your own to encapsulate the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need a algo to do it and not java syntax.

You could subtract the Second start time from First stop time, and put a threshold on the difference depending on what is an acceptable overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in pure Java, use a `Calendar` object and `compareTo() == 0`

For overlap, set seconds, minutes, etc. to 0 until you get the desired "precision".

Alternatively (for more fine grained precision), convert both to `long` and use `Math.abs( t1 - t2 )` to get the difference in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following example code (hope you do not mind deprecated APIs as this is just an example).

```
public class DateOverlapTest {

    public static void main(final String... args) {

        Date start1 = new Date(2011, 6, 21, 9, 0);
        Date stop1 = new Date(2011, 6, 21, 10, 0);

        Date start2 = new Date(2011, 6, 21, 9, 5);
        Date stop2 = new Date(2011, 6, 21, 10, 30);

        System.out.println("Start1: " + start1);
        System.out.println("Stop1 : " + stop1);
        System.out.println("Start2: " + start2);
        System.out.println("Stop2 : " + stop2);

        // start2 has to be before or equal stop1 and
        // stop2 has to be after or equal start1
        boolean overlap = start2.compareTo(stop1) <= 0
                && stop2.compareTo(start1) >= 0;

        System.out.println("Overlaps: " + overlap);

    }

}
```

output is:

```
Start1: Fri Jul 21 09:00:00 CEST 3911
Stop1 : Fri Jul 21 10:00:00 CEST 3911
Start2: Fri Jul 21 09:05:00 CEST 3911
Stop2 : Fri Jul 21 10:30:00 CEST 3911
Overlaps: true
```